Adding a unique constraint that includes a nullable value
I have the following entity model class:
public class RoutePermission
{
    public Guid? UserId { get; set; }
    public Guid? DistrictId { get; set; }
    public Guid RouteId { get; set; }
    public bool Admin { get; set; }
}

I want a unique constraint added to achieve the following behavior:
{ routeId: 1, userId: 1, districtId: null, admin: true } // Allowed
{ routeId: 1, userId: null, districtId: 1, admin: true } // Allowed
{ routeId: 2, userId: 1, districtId: null, admin: true } // Allowed
{ routeId: 2, userId: 1, districtId: null, admin: true } // Not Allowed

The problem is that no error was being thrown when inserting the 4th record.
This is the model validation I started with:
modelBuilder.Entity<RoutePermission>()
   .HasIndex(rp =>
      new { rp.RouteId, rp.DistrictId, rp.UserId }
   )
   .IsUnique();

No dice. I did a lot of research, and I came across .HasFilter(null), which supposedly overrides a default behavior of skipping a validation if any of the validated fields are null. I've got it! Nope, still nothing.
I did finally discover what the real issue was. Postgres considers the null value as distinct from another, so null != null (just like objects in JavaScript). Now I understood why Postgres was not throwing any errors for the 4th record in the example above. But how to fix it?

ChatGPT suggested using COALESCE to replace the null value with a value that would be equal to another like it. Although null != null, if we replaced the null value with 0 for example, 0 = 0 and the validation should work as intended.
Alas, still no dice.

The real solution is noted in the documentation, and available from EF Core 7.0+:
.AreNullsDistinct(false);
This adds the NULLS NOT DISTINCT option to the CREATE INDEX command.
FINAL SOLUTION/ #TLDR
   modelBuilder
   .Entity<RoutePermission>()
   .HasIndex(rp =>
      new { rp.RouteId, rp.DistrictId, rp.UserId }
   )
   .IsUnique()
   .AreNullsDistinct(false);

